# How to make Smooth Navigational Menu to show sub menu in UP direction rather than down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am using [Smooth Navigational Menu (v1.51)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) in my asp.net project, So far it works great i can change the property to make it vertical or horizontal Menu.

only issue have with it is that i am not able change the direction of the menu to open it in the `up` direction.

if this menu is at the footer section then part of menu wont show up as show in example 
http://jsfiddle.net/JjbqA/7/

How can i change the direction of Sub menu to `UP` direction rather than down.

```
ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //Menu DIV id
    orientation: 'v', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#804000", "#482400"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})
```

Comment: need to customize the javascript.

Comment: do you care if its animated in ie? If not, you can do it entirely with css and forget the pluggin.

Comment: I am not a JS or CSS guy i was just looking to see if can be done with property